# What is the most suggested solution for shared storage on Amazon Web Services?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am about to deploy a nfs-like shared storage on AWS infrastructure that will be accessed by about 10-15 linux servers. What I could just check is that AWS doesn't provide such solution (at least as I know we can't plug an ebs on more than 1 server), I just tried to use some s3-fs but I haven't trusted any of the available solutions as since as all of them seems to be too unstable. What have you guys been using that could deliver some performance and at same time security?

All suggestions are welcome, I would appreciate it a lot.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with using NFS?

Comment: In your point of view is it secure to use NFS on the AWS network? As far as I know NFS will send and receive files through an unencrypted channel.

Comment: Use a [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).  I frequently use NFS to share files to app servers in an autoscale group inside a VPC.